# Increment in UPDATE query not going over 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, increment

I have another problem which I have spent hours on understanding and rewriting. On the UPDATE query I included countr=countr+1. I successfully received the keyWords from the mobile application and was also able to store them in the database. The problem is, whenever the same keyWord is passed for the fifth time a new row is created. Instead of adding 1 to the countr of that keyWord. It's as if the countr is limited on holding number 4 only.

Is it because of a mistake I did with the UPDATE query or is it because of something else I missed?

Here is my code:

```
$con= mysqli_connect("...","...","...") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
mysqli_select_db($con,"...");
$sql= "SELECT keyWord FROM searchedWords";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if($row['keyWord']==$_POST[keyWord])
{
  $upD="UPDATE searchedWords SET countr = countr + 1";
     while (!mysqli_query($con,$upD))
    {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
else
{
   $insertIn="INSERT INTO `searchedWords`( `keyWord`, `countr`) values ('$_POST[keyWord]',1)";
 while (!mysqli_query($con,$insertIn))
    {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

Here is the table where the keyWords and countr are stored:

[image: the DB table]

It just wont go over 4. Android should have a countr of 9 and Java 5.
What do you think did I do wrong?

Comment: `$upD="UPDATE searchedWords SET countr = countr + 1";` - Shouldn't you have a where clause here?  e.g. `WHERE keyword = '".$row['keyWord']."'"`; Otherwise you're incrementing the counter for every keyword in the table (use prepared statements, as you're using MySQLi, obviously)

Comment: I'd also trim the $_POST values as to remove any extraneous spaces

Comment: do a var_dump on row['keyWord'] and $_POST['keyWord']

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST[keyWord]
```

should be

```
$_POST['keyWord']
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify which row to update in the update query otherwise it will update all the values...and another fault i can see but

I am not sure that`($row['keyWord']==$_POST[keyWord])` in this code `$_POST['keyword']` the keyword should be in quotes....Hope it will help

Comment: I'll try putting in the quotes. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing changed though.

Comment: But still i think that the problem s with this statement if($row['keyWord']==$_POST['keyWord]') because here $row['keyword'] is an array and it matches only its first value or no value with the $_POST['keyword']...you need to use foreach loop perhaps

Comment: The value of $_POST['keyword'] depends on whatever keyword the user of our mobile application searches for in the Online Public Access Catalogue.